# How do I continue list indentation in Pandoc Markdown when converting to PDF?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am facing an issue with using Pandoc Markdown. I want my pdf document to look something like below (please notice how the indentation of the list items continue after adding images)

1. Point a

   Image for point a here.

   Continuation of point a.
2. Point b

   Image for point b here.

   Continuation of point b

However, no matter what I try, I can't get the indentation to look right. After inserting the image, either the indentation is lost (<4 spaces) or it starts showing as code block (>=4 spaces).

How do I indent a list item when I want to insert a figure in it?

> Edit #1

Markdown that I am using:

```
a. Point a starts here.\
[image for point a](image1.png)\
Point a continued.

b. Point b starts here.\
[image for point b](image2.png)\

    i. sub point 1 in point b.
    ii. sub point 2 in point b

continue point b here.
```

How it looks:

[image]

> Edit #2

Following @mb21's suggestions, (copying the format exactly + adding my images), I get the following output:

[image: The continuation of points after images is not indented correctly.]

The continuation of points after the images is not indented correctly.

Updated markdown:

```
## Problem 1 ##

a. Point a starts here.

   ![Frequency of fires in a given year](wildfires.png){height=50px}

   Point a continued.

b. Point b starts here.

   ![Frequency of fires in a given year](wildfires.png){height=50px}

   i. sub point 1 in point b.
   ii. sub point 2 in point b

   continue point b here.
```

Comment: I figured out that I can add "\" after "Point a" and then another "\" after "Image for point a here." to indent the lines correctly. However, the space between the image and the text becomes too narrow and doesn't look nice. I don't know how to add an image to show what I mean. I am sorry :(

Comment: What you describe seems like it should work, so I suspect you are encountering a rather subtle issue that isn't obvious without seeing your Markdown. Please edit your question to include the actual Markdown you are using in a code block (or at least a simplified version of it).

Comment: @Waylan Thanks. I have added how my markdown is structured. I also added a screenshot of final pdf generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct indentation for what you want is:

```
## Problem 1

a. Point a starts here.

   ![image for point a](http://cdn.northlight-images.co.uk/downloadable_2/media_check.jpg){width=5cm}

   Point a continued.

b. Point b starts here.

   ![image for point b](http://cdn.northlight-images.co.uk/downloadable_2/media_check.jpg){width=5cm}

   i. sub point 1 in point b.
   ii. sub point 2 in point b

   continue point b here.
```

See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items

The above results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I have updated my question with the results that I got from using your suggestions.

Comment: @AkshayGaur works for me... see update. Are you sure you didn't mangle some spaces when copy-pasting? Also make sure you're using the lastest pandoc version...

Comment: I have pandoc version 1.19.2.4 (installed using apt repository) I will try and update it to 2.2.3.2 and report back.

Comment: I updated to the latest pandoc and it works now. I wasted 3-4 hours trying to get this to work which I could have used towards completing the assignment. And here I am trying to finish the assignment at 4:30 AM. :(
Thank you @mb21