# How do I continue list indentation after a table in Pandoc when converting to PDF?

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175805/how-do-i-continue-list-indentation-in-pandoc-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf) but this time, instead of dealing with images, I am dealing with tables.

I would like to insert a table within a list item and then continue the indentation of that list point.

Markdown I am using:

```
## Problem 1 ##
a. This point starts here.
   Some stuff here.

--------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
0 bit in error  1 bit in error 2 bits in error 3 bits in error 4 bits in error
--------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
NNNN            ENNN, NENN,    EENN, ENEN,     EEEN, EENE,     EEEE
                NNEN, NNNE     ENNE, NEEN,     ENEE, EEEN
                               NENE, NNEE

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Point a continued here. This doesn't indent properly.
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL)

Pandoc Version: 2.2.3.2

Latex Version (pdflatex): 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18

Current output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indent the whole content of your list item by [four spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists), including the table:

```
## Problem 1 ##

a.  This point starts here.
    Some stuff here.

    --------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
    0 bit in error  1 bit in error 2 bits in error 3 bits in error 4 bits in error
    --------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
    NNNN            ENNN, NENN,    EENN, ENEN,     EEEN, EENE,     EEEE
                    NNEN, NNNE     ENNE, NEEN,     ENEE, EEEN
                                   NENE, NNEE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Point a continued here. This doesn't indent properly.
```

This ensures that both, the table and the following paragraph, are recognized as belonging to the list item.

Comment: In commonmark and newer pandoc versions, [the rule is actually](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items): "indented to line up with the first non-space content after the list marker" (i.e. after the dot in `a.`)